# JavaScript: Filter object, keeping unique properties

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I need to filter against and return a new object. The goal is to get all ids that contain "A" in `val`, BUT only include ids with a unique `val`.

Below is what I'm currently doing, but I wonder if there's a more efficient way to do this. As can be seen when you run the code snippet, the new object should look like this:

```
{
  "id1": {
    "val": "AAA"
  },
  "id4": {
    "val": "ABC"
  }
}
```

```js
const obj = {
  id1: {
    val: 'AAA',
  },
  id2: {
    val: 'BBB',
  },
  id3: {
    val: 'AAA',
  },
  id4: {
    val: 'ABC',
  },
};

// Filtered object
const obj2 = {};
let matched = '';

for (const key in obj) {
  if (matched.indexOf(obj[key].val) < 0 && obj[key].val.indexOf('A') > -1) {
    obj2[key] = obj[key];
    matched += obj[key].val + ' ';
  }
}

console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Are you relying on the order of properties to determine which key wins for a given `val`?

Comment: *Efficient*? I guess, though a Set would be nicer than a string for `matched`. The other improvements are nitpicks, not efficiency bonuses - consider `.includes` and `Object.entries`, and maybe filter the entries and use `Object.fromEntries` to turn it into a new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building up a string for `matched`, you should use a `Set` (O(1) string comparisons for each operation instead of searching an increasingly long string in time proportional to the length of that string – and not running into issues with keys that contain spaces). [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is also a nice modern alternative to `indexOf(…) > -1`, although not faster.

Also, when using objects to store key/value mappings, you should use prototypeless objects – starting from `Object.create(null)` – to avoid setter weirdness (mostly `__proto__`) and tempting but fragile methods (name collisions with `Object.prototype`), and as a matter of good practice even when that isn’t a concern. Or just use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)s instead.

```js
const obj = {
  id1: {val: 'AAA'},
  id2: {val: 'BBB'},
  id3: {val: 'AAA'},
  id4: {val: 'ABC'},
};

// Filtered object
const obj2 = Object.create(null);
const matched = new Set();

for (const key in obj) {
  if (!matched.has(obj[key].val) && obj[key].val.includes('A')) {
    obj2[key] = obj[key];
    matched.add(obj[key].val);
  }
}

console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips on `Object.create(null)` and using sets -- I did a performance comparison on JSBench.me and using sets was over 40% faster than doing the string concatenation method I was using.